# Kubernetes DNS - two Spring boot applications using feign

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, dns, feign

In my local Windows Docker-Desktop I have a runnning Kubernetes.

In a dedicated namespace (my-namespace) I have deployed two Spring boot applications and I have defined the corresponding services:

```
app1 -----> app1-service (port: 8080, name: http)
```

and

```
app2 -----> app2-service (port: 8080, name: http)
```

According to the Kubernetes documentation, the DNS name for my service has the form
`my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example`, so in this case the two DNS names are:

```
app1-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

and

```
app2-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

Having these, how should I define the URL for the FeignClients in app1?

What I have already tested:

```
http://app2-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local/api
http://app2-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080/api
```

but without any success.